# Odoo - Search products with code instead of id

Tags: mysql, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

I am using odoo 10 and I have two models Order_Line and Products.

**OrderLine**

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
_name = 'order_line'
_description = 'Order Lines'

name = fields.Char()
products = fields.Many2one('amgl.products', String='Products')
```

**Products**

```
class Products(models.Model):
_name = 'products'
_description = 'Products'
    _sql_constraints = [
    ('uniq_poduct_code', 'unique(product_code)', 'Product Code already exists!')
]

name = fields.Char()
product_code = Char()
```

Now i am trying to create order_line from a csv file and in csv file the customer is providing me 'Product Code' instead of `Id`. How to handle this that, we use product code and system automatically fills the products associated with that product code.

**Note :**

`Product Code` in products table is also unique, so there is no chance of duplicating.

**CSV template:**

```
customer/account_number,customer/first_name,customer/last_name,customer/account_type,order/transaction_id,order/products/product_code,order/quantity,order/customer_id/id
```

Comment: Could you show the CSV template that you would like to import please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**: there are no products stored in the database with any of the product codes the customer is giving to you

If the product codes haven't been created yet in the database, you should have two CSV files (*Products.csv* and *OrderLine.csv*). The first one must have three columns (`id`, `name` and `product_code`). The second one must have three columns too (`id`, `name` and `products/id`). So you would only have to make up a XML ID under the `id` column in *Products.csv* and call this XML ID from the respective row of the column `products/id` of the file *OrderLine.csv*.

**Case 2**: the product codes the customer has given to you belong to existing products in the database

Now, the customer has given you product codes of products which already exist in the database. In this case you don't have to create a *Products.csv* file. You need to know which are the XML IDs of the products which have the product codes the customer gave to you. For that, you can go through the interface of Odoo to the tree view of the model `products` (if this view doesn't exist, you must create it). Then, you'll have to select all records (click on the number 80 of the top right corner to show more records per page if you need it). Once all of them are selected, click on `More` button and afterwars on `Export`. Select the column `product_code` and `name` and afterwards proceed. Save the generated CSV file as *Products.csv*, for example. Open it, you'll see all the XML ID of the exported products (if they hadn't XML ID, after the exportation they'll do -an exportation generates XML ID for each exported record if it doesn't have anyone-). Now, I guess the customer has given you something like a file with columns *Name of the order line*, *Product code*, so replace the *Product code* column values with the respective XML IDs of the products you have just exported. So in the end youu should have one file to import, *OrderLine.csv*, with `id`, `name` and `products/id` columns.

**Case 3**: there are some product codes belonging to existing products stored in the database and there are some ones which still don't exist

In this case you will have to combine both cases 1 and 2, first, export the products as described in case 2, and then, create a new one with the products whose code doesn't exist yet, as described in case 1. Then replace the product codes the customer gave to you with the respective ones as described in case 2.

**Note**: this process will give you a lot of time if you have thousands of records to import and you replace them manually. In this case it is mandatory to create a macro in your CSV editor which does the replacements (with search and replace). For example, with LibreOffice you can do macros with Python.

> **Example** (Case 3)
>
> The customer has given you a file of order lines, with two lines:
>
> - Name: OL A, Product Code: AAA
> - Name: OL B, Product Code: BBB
>
> You export products from Odoo interface and you get a file with one
>   line:
>
> `id,name,product_code
>   __export__.products_a,"Product A","AAA"`
>
> You look for the coincidences of the product codes in both files, and
>   do the replacements in a copy of the customer file, so now you have
>   this:
>
> - Name: OL A, Product Code: `__export__.products_a`
> - Name: OL B, Product Code: BBB
>
> Then you create a new CSV *Products.csv* and put in there the products
>   whose product code don't exist yet:
>
> `id,name,product_code
>   __import__.products_b,"Product B","BBB"`
>
> Now apply the replacements again comparing this new file with the one
>   we had, and you will get this:
>
> - Name: OL A, Product Code: `__export__.products_a`
> - Name: OL B, Product Code: `__import__.products_b`
>
> Convert this file to a right CSV format for Odoo, and save it as
>   *OrderLine.csv*:
>
> `id,name,products/id
>   __import__.order_line_1,"OL A",__export__.products_a
>   __import__.order_line_2,"OL B",__import__.products_b`
>
> And finally, import the files, and take into account: import
>   *Products.csv* before *OrderLine.csv*.

**EDIT**

I think it should be better to waste a bit of time in programming a macro for your CSV editor (Excel, LibreOffice, Open Office or whatever), but if you're desperated and you need to do this only through Odoo, I came up with an awful workaround, but at least, it should work too.

1.Create a new `Char` field named `product_code` in `order_line` model (it would be there temporaly).

2.Modify the ORM create method of this model:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    product_id = False
    product_code = vals.get('product_code', False)
    if product_code:
        product = self.env['products'].search([
            ('product_code', '=', product_code)
        ])
        if product:
            product_id = product[0].id
    vals.update({
        'products': product_id,
    })
    return super(OrderLine, self).create(vals)
```

3.Copy the file which the customer's sent you, rename the headers properly, and rename the column `order/products/product_code` as `product_code`. Import the CSV file. Each importation of records will call the ORM create method of `order_line` model.

After the importation you'll have in the database the order lines rightly related to the products.

When you've finished you'll have to remember to remove the code you've added (and also remove the column `product_code` from `order_line` model in the database, in order to remove junk).

Comment: Well, its very descriptive and informative and my case is # 2. Where customer has already given me the product_code that they use in there company and they will provide same product_code in csv file. Now if we come to solution the solution you provided against #2 is that we have to manually put the ids against the each line and i am assuming a way where it happens automatically.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a workaround. Not clean at all, but should work without the need of programming macros.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You can create a transient model with the fields that you are using in the CSV. And applying the idea of @forvas:

```py
class ImportOrderLines(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'import.order.lines'

    product_code = Char()

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        product_id = False
        product_code = vals.get('product_code', False)
        if product_code:
            product = self.env['products'].search([
                ('product_code', '=', product_code)
            ])
            if product:
                product_id = product[0].id

        self.env['order_line'].create({
            'products': product_id,
        })
        return False   # you don't need to create the record in the transient model
```

You can go to the list view of this transient model and import like in any other model, with the `base_import` view.

**Solution 2**

You could create a wizard in order to import the CSV to create the Order Lines.
Check the following source code. You must assing the method `import_order_lines` to a button in the wizard.

```py
import base64
import magic
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO
import codecs

from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from openerp.exceptions import Warning


class ImportDefaultCodeWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'import.default_code.wizard'

    name = fields.Char(
        string='File name',
    )

    file = fields.Binary(
        string='ZIP file to import to Odoo',
        required=True,
    )

    @api.multi
    def import_order_lines(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        content = base64.decodestring(self.file)

        if codecs.BOM_UTF8 == content[:3]:  # remove "byte order mark" (windows)
            content = content[3:]

        file_type = magic.from_buffer(content, mime=True)

        if file_type == 'text/plain':
            self._generate_order_line_from_csv(content)
            return self._show_result_wizard()

        raise Warning(
            _('WRONG FILETYPE'),
            _('You should send a CSV file')
        )

    def _show_result_wizard(self):
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': self._name,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'target': 'new',
            'context': self.env.context,
        }        

    def _generate_order_line_from_csv(self, data):
        try:
            reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(data))
        except Exception:
            raise Warning(
                _('ERROR getting data from csv file'
                '\nThere was some error trying to get the data from the csv file.'
                '\nMake sure you are using the right format.'))
        n = 1

        for row in reader:
            n += 1
            self._validate_data(n, row)

            default_code = row.get('default_code', False)


            order_line = {
                'default_code': self._get_product_id(default_code),

                # here you should add all the order line fields
            }

            try:
                self.env['order_line'].create(order_line)
            except Exception:
                raise Warning(
                    _('The order line could not be created.'
                    '\nROW: %s') % n
                )

    def _validate_data(self, n, row):
        csv_fields = [
            'default_code',
        ]
        """ here is where you should add the CSV fields in order to validate them
                customer/account_number, customer/first_name, customer/last_name, 
                customer/account_type, order/transaction_id, order/products/product_code ,order/quantity, order/customer_id/id
        """


        for key in row:
            if key not in csv_fields:
                raise Warning(_('ERROR\nThe file format is not right.'
                                '\nCheck the column names and the CSV format'
                                '\nKEY: %s' % key))

        if row.get('default_code', False) == '':
            raise Warning(
                _('ERROR Validating data'),
                _('The product code should be filled.'
                '\nROW: %s') % n
            )

    def _get_product_id(self, default_code):
        if partner_id:
            product_obj = self.env['product.product'].search([
                ('default_code', '=', default_code),
            ])
            if len(product_code_obj) == 1:
                return product_obj.default_code
            else:
                raise Warning(
                    _('ERROR Validating data'),
                    _('The product code should be filled.'
                    '\nROW: %s') % n
                )        
            return False
```

Comment: I am getting almost, what you are trying to do but this will not give us many features what Odoo gives, Like preview, validate etc. I mean the Odoo way is fancy. So is there any way we can inherit `base_import` and we do customization is some specific method ?

Comment: That form is used for all the models, so If you adapt it to your needs the rest of the importations are not going to work. And if you still want to modify it I'm afraid that is not going to be easy. If you want to see CSV in a fancy way you can open it with LibreOffice Calc. If you and only validate the CSV you can force a rollback after all the creates

Comment: And if you check other importation modules, they create another view such as the module [product_variant_csv_import](https://github.com/akretion/odoo-usability/tree/10.0/product_variant_csv_import) or they do kind of what I do, check the screenshots of the module [bi_generic_import](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/bi_generic_import/)

Comment: You can create a temp `one2many` field in the wizard to show all the values as well

Comment: I have updated my answer with another idea @ancient. Check if it is helpful for you, please

Comment: In solution # 1, do i need to inherit the model from `base.import` class ?

Comment: Nope, you are creating a new model there, but actually it is a dummy model where nothing should be stored. If you don't understand it I can show you the complete example. You can import in this model with the same `Import` button as the rest of models do. If you only use the solution of @forvas you are going to modify the general create of the `order_line` and that's dangerous because you only need to do that during the importation of data. In addition you will have a empty column for each custom field you want to import.

Comment: I use the approach showed by you guys and then i modified the `base_import.py` method in my inherited class. Thanks for your effort too

Answer (score 0):

You can search by product_code like so:

```
@api.model
def search_by_code(self, code):
    result = self.env['products'].search([('product_code', '=', code)])
```

Comment: i know this search method and domain filter. But when i will be importing from csv then this will method will not work